# Mixed Language Negotiation (Prefix and domain) in D7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

We have a single code base and database for all the 3 languages of a certain website:

- http://example.com/ - default, no prefix, English
- http://example.com/pt - pt prefix, Portuguese
- http://example.com/ru - ru prefix, Russian

However, we now want to change the Russian domain to http://example.ru (no prefix)

What's the best way to attain this without affecting the previous domains and urls?

Best regards

Comment: Although i don't know much about the drupal, but I guess this could be done via .htaccess